# Not sure why the compiler is complaining ... implicit declaration of function strchrnul

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files, compiler-warnings

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int valid_line(char *cur_line) {
    if (*cur_line == '#') {
        return 0;
    }

    char *end = strchrnul(cur_line, '#');

    while(end > cur_line && isspace(*end)) end--;
    return (!(*cur_line == *end));
}
```

I am going through the line and am getting rid of leading and trailing white spaces and anything that occurs after the '#' (including the '#').

My compiler is saying this:

```
parser.c:20:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strchrnul’ [-Wimplicit-    function-declaration]
parser.c:20:14: warning: initialisation makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

EVen though I have `string.h` above.

Could someone please explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`strchrnul()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchrnul) is a GNU extension, and you can get this function included warning free via a [feature test macro](http://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros).

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE  // required for strchrnul()

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>  // required for strchrnul()
#include <stdlib.h>

static int valid_line(char *cur_line) {
    if (*cur_line == '#') {
        return 0;
    }

    char *end = strchrnul(cur_line, '#');

    while(end > cur_line && isspace(*end)) end--;
    return (!(*cur_line == *end));
}
```

Please note from the second linked man page, the placement of the `#define` is important:

> NOTE: In order to be effective, a feature test macro must be defined before including any header files

Comment: for some reason this was the top search result for "[`memmem`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmem.3.html) implicit declaration",, and what do you know, the manpage says to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `gcc` compiler, don't use `-std=c89` or `-std=c99` but rather use `-std=gnu89` or `-std=gnu99` as `strchrnul` is a GNU extension.

Comment: im not using anything ... should it still be complaining?

Comment: @cxzp how do you compile your source file?

Comment: `gcc -o main main.o parser.o -Wall` as in i am using gcc but havent set any standards

Comment: or are there default standards that it assumes hence the warnings

Comment: @cxzp `gcc -o main main.o parser.o -Wall` is how you are linking your files, how do you compile `parser.c`?

Comment: In that case you should not receive this warning.